# Search functionality returning wrong results on multi-lingual site

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual, search

Search works well for only one language on my site.

My website is on 2 languages -- French and English -- but the search works for French only and not working as desired for English.

Example:

If I search for `camion` in French language, I get:

- Camion Freightliner Coronado 2016
- Camion Freightliner Cascadia 2015
- Camion Western Star 4900S 2015

If I search for `camion` in English language, I get:

- 2016 Freightliner Coronado Truck
- 2015 Freightliner Cascadia Truck
- 2015 Western Star 4900S Truck

If I search for `truck` in English language, I get:

- No results

If I search for `truck` in French language, I get:

- Aucun résultats

I don't know where the translate text is stored on the database.

Comment: How is this question tagged for both Joomla 3.x AND Joomla2.5.  Please edit your question to clarify your Joomla version.  Are you using Joomla's core search or are you using a third-party extension?

Comment: Joomla core search